# error while calling api in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am very very new in ionic and angular , i follow all the step that ionic 
provide at the blog to config api http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/

after follow all the step when i try to console the result which is store in the variable that return undefined
here is the code of  provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class ApiServiceProvider {
   link = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
   data :any;
   constructor(public http: Http) {
     console.log('Hello ApiServiceProvider Provider');

     this.load();
    }
load() {
    if (this.data) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(this.link)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data.results;
                resolve(this.data);
            });
    });
  }
}
```

here is the code for page/home.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController ,ActionSheetController , AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { ResultPage } from '../result/result';
 import { ApiServiceProvider } from '../../providers/api-service/api-service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   providers: [ApiServiceProvider]
 })
  export class HomePage {
   users: any;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl:AlertController, public actionCtrl:ActionSheetController,public apiProvider:ApiServiceProvider) {
    this.getUsers();
   }
   getUsers() {
     this.apiProvider.load()
     .then(data => {
       this.users = data;
    });
   console.log(this.users);
 }
```

any help is appreciated. thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside `load()` is asynchronous, meaning it will take some time to complete. While that code is working, the next statement will to executed. In your case, the next statement is `console.log(this.users)`.

This leads to `console.log(this.users)` being executed before `load()` is completed, and `this.users` will therefor be `undefined`.

Solve this by moving the `console.log` **inside** the `then` callback like this:

```
getUsers() {
  this.apiProvider.load()
    .then(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
}
```

I recommend you to read up on how [**PROMISES**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies) in javascript works :)

Comment: you are great thankx a lot , i spend 3 days on this and you just see that code and correct in just 1 attempt.. thanks a lot